# React - dynamically create nav from components on page

Tags: reactjs

I have a [stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sndxmb?file=index.tsx)

Its a super a simple app with 3 components on a page

Ive been trying to find a way to dynamically create a nav from the components displayed

I was hoping I could somehow update the nav array using setNav from the components and then loop through that to create the nav

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import About from "./About";
import Products from "./Products";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState([]);

  const about = true;
  const products = true;
  const contact = true;

  return (
    // <nav>
    //   <ul>
    //   {nav.map(items => {
    //     <li>{item}</li>
    //   })}
    //   </ul>
    // </nav>

    <div>
      {about && <About />}
      {products && <Products />}
      {contact && <Contact />}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You can put all the Nav Elements in its own component , then import the component and  loop through it .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const nav = [
    { component: <About />, show: true },
    { component: <Products />, show: false },
    { component: <Contact />, show: true }
  ];

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {nav
          .filter(({ show }) => show)
          .map(item => (
            <li>{item.component}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

I've created an array of objects which contain component and a property which indicates whether a component is shown. Then, I filter only shown components and display them.